# best java web framework with support for html5 development

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, web-applications, frameworks

Which are the more suitable options of java web frameworks that have a full support for html5 front end development?

Comment: What is the result of your research?

Comment: Have you faced any specific problem when using any of the frameworks !!!

Comment: What is "more suitable" can be subjective, or be different in different contexts. State the criteria for evaluation, and people will be able to give precise answers. Otherwise you risk your question being closed for being "not constructive".

Comment: Ok, maybe my question isn't concise or well wrote. My doubt is choose a java backend technology that allow me develop the frontend  using pure Html5, Css3 and javascript. I'm interested in this kind of integration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for some sort of front end Java framework, such as JSF. I had a similar problem recently and after extensive serach my company decided to go with Primefaces JSF. Primefaces is a JSF framework with amazing community and support that allows you to build html5 very quickly and efficiently:

http://www.primefaces.org/

They have very aggresive release cycle and continiue adding components that you can easily use in your web app.